# How to design this Grid view xml page?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-gridview

I want to design xml page this type.[image] I tried many of the code. Every time new problems are come. I need bottom navigation bar is fixed. In grid view ,i want `android:numColums=3`, `android:verticalSpacing` and   `android:horizontalSpacing` Same(Look like instagram profile view grid images ).

**XMl Code:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   tools:context=".MainSettingClass">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="175dp"
    android:background="#dadada"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_button_background"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amsc_txt_fbusername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

   </LinearLayout>

  <GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/grid_test"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:columnWidth="85dp"
    android:numColumns="3"/>

  <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_gallery"/>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: what you did ??

Comment: _I tried many of the code..._ Where  is your code?

Comment: Show what efforts you have made the achieve the same?

Comment: Show us whatever code you tried

Comment: wait i will post the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your design you need `scrollview` for 2 above components and your BottomNavigationView is fix (not movable).

In your code you are not using scrollview first and second i'm not sure why you're using framelayout!

Here's my code which is exactly as per your given design try this if any concern you can ask! :)

**Here's my code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_gallery">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/rel_titleHolder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#dadada"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/amsc_txt_fbusername"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="TextView" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/grid_test"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:columnWidth="85dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                android:numColumns="3"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @bub Thank you for your guidance, i'll make sure this.. :)
P.S check i already did! :)